# Why popup form is showing behind another popup form when i clicked 3 times in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

Below is the code to display my popup form, but when i clicked 3 times this pop-up show in behind another pop up

```
 protected void grid_RowCommand2(object sender, ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandArgs.CommandArgument == "Skoring") 
                {
                    ASPxPopupControl3.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you may be using DevExpress components? If so, please [edit] your question to include that tag, so that experts in DevExpress will see the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my flyout panel, it seems that while the animation for the control is in progress. It does not allocate the display area to the control while the animation is still busy, this will result in your controls overlapping one another.

I was able to solve this problem by putting my flyout panel inside another control (in my case, I chose a transparent panel control) and let the panel control be loaded instantly when the event occurs. The animation can now continue while the space needed is already allocated to that control.